# AioHttp error discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi i can't start my bot discord

```html
root@boot:~/mdrk/discord.py# python3.5 discordbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 601, in _create_direct_connection
    local_addr=self._local_addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 695, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 682, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 439, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
OSError: [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('104.16.59.5', 443)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 304, in connect
    yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 578, in _create_connection
    transport, proto = yield from self._create_direct_connection(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 624, in _create_direct_connection
    (req.host, req.port, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 113] Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [Connect call failed ('104.16.59.5', 443)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discordbot.py", line 121, in <module>
    client.run('token')
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/client.py", line 518, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/client.py", line 489, in start
    yield from self.login(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/client.py", line 416, in login
    yield from getattr(self, '_login_' + str(n))(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/client.py", line 346, in _login_1
    data = yield from self.http.static_login(token, bot=is_bot)
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = yield from self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/root/mdrk/discord.py/discord/http.py", line 137, in request
    r = yield from self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 555, in __iter__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 198, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 314, in connect
    .format(key, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 113] Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [Connect call failed ('104.16.59.5', 443)]]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f21a06dae48>
```

I need you help
This is an educational open source project with many sub-projects. The one I am studying currently is the 'crawler' project. It requires python 3.4+ and aiohttp 1.2+. My current setup is Windows 10, Python 3.6.1, and aiohttp 2.0.4.

Strangely, my tests do not run and it is related to aiohttp. Can anybody familiar with aiohttp tell me why?

Here is the output I get:

Comment: Can you use a basic bot from the discord.py github to test the connection to the server?

Comment: No i can't check the code :
https://pastebin.com/NyP5qmHN

Comment: Where are you hosting the bot from?  Some services restrict websocket access, which discord.py relies on

Comment: The bot walked niquel, I left 30minutes, I come back I want to restart the bot & error I restart the server ect, I do not know
He was walking really well, his not coming from the code, nor from the welcome car it was walking before ...

Comment: Discord uses cloudflare to filter traffic, I think cloudlfare banned your ip adress because you were sending too many requests. Try to send the requests via proxy. Or your hosting provider banned it because you got too many traffic, try to do this via VPS server :)